# scalaj-collections : Can I use this in Java?

Tags: java, scala

I found [scalaj-collections](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-collection) and it looks like it's the only library that will let me convert `Java.util.List` to `scala.collection.Seq`.

Can I use this library in my Java project? Or is exclusive to Scala. I've included its dependencies in my maven pom.xml and I can use the library in my code. But I don't see how to apply the `.asScala` method in a Java project

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need thirdparty dependencies to convert between scala and java collections. Scala library has set of adapters named [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$).

Just import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and you'll get implicit conversions between scala and java collection interfaces, so you can pass them as the arguments to functions, call scala-specific methods on java collections (and vice versa) and so on.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val sl = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
val jl : java.util.List[Int] = sl
jl.map(_ + 1)
val sl2 : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = jl
```

Answer (score 0):

`Java.util.List to scala.collection.Seq`

Scala has its own List (scala.collection.List). In addition, List has a function called toSeq(). I believe this is what you want.